# Storage Permissions on Android 10 device differs with sdk target 30 vs target 27

Tags: android, file-access

I have a file access routine common to two version of an app (here's the complete method):

```
public void openDataRestore(CfgTab tableFileEnum){
    cfgStatFileName = sensorCalibFileNames[tableFileEnum.ordinal()]+".cfg"; // "FrAccTab.cfg"
    File apdatSubDir;
    if(System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")!=null){
        try {
            String extPath;
            extPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE"); // "/sdcard"
            String fullPathName = extPath+getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.dat_dir); // "/sdcard/apdat/"
            apdatSubDir = new File(fullPathName);
            File[] reportFiles = apdatSubDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.matches(cfgStatFileName);  // "FrAccTab.cfg"
                }
            });
            if(reportFiles!=null&&reportFiles.length==1) {
                File reportFile = reportFiles[0];
                cfgFr = new FileReader(reportFile);
                cfgIn = new BufferedReader(cfgFr);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            if(ioe.getMessage().contains("Permission denied")){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activeFragmentView.getContext());
                builder2.setMessage(ioe.getMessage()+"\n\n"+getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.store_perms))
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                confirmOpenRestoreFile = true;
                            }
                        });
                builder2.show();
                return;
            }
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

On the older deployment this works with Manifest permissions API 29: Target 27:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But on the newer one API 30 Target 30 it only works if one modifies the manifest thus:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
 ....
</application>
```

My test device is Android 10 which implies API 29 which then means there's more trouble ahead for the code segment using AS4.0's recommended API 30 target 30? An alternative file access procedure that I tried:

```
File targetItem = new File(fullPathName+cfgStatFileName);
if(targetItem!=null){
   cfgFr = new FileReader(targetItem);
   cfgIn = new BufferedReader(cfgFr);
}
```

generates an IOException in API 30 Target 30 when creating new FileReader(targetItem), and is curiously more comforting than the quiet failure of trying to open the subdirectory first.
And, File.mkdirs() does not seem appropriate in a read-only context, which is what the newer app is trying to read from the older one's writes. One ideally needs the two to coexist on a specific platform?.

PS: I removed the superfluous mkdirs() and also tried to recreate the error by undoing the Manifest requestLegacyExternalStorage. But the problem did not recur since apparently Android 10 now knows this new version has premission granted. So the problem is for new apps because the old apps had permission before Android upgraded from 9 to 10 ...

Comment: `apdatSubDir.mkdirs();
File[] reportFiles = apdatSubDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {` ??? mkdirs followed by listFiles? If you just created the dir it will be empty.

Comment: `apdatSubDir.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you do check the return value and stop if it is false.

Comment: `new File(fullPathName+cfgStatFileName)` ?? Pretty unclear!! Nobody knows which full path that would be.

Comment: Sorry for using symbolics. when using getEnv(..EXTERNAL_STORAGE) it begins with /sdcard followed (in this case) 'apdat' and cfgFile 'FrAccTab.cfg to get "/sdcard/apdat/FrAccTab.cfg". I also thought the semantic of storage had changed, so using getEnv(...ANDROID_STORAGE) resulted in "/storage/sdcard0/apdat/FrAccTab.cfg", physically the same file, but inaccessible and resulted is the same outcome.

Comment: Please put all info in your code to make it readable. Dont use comments to write a post

Comment: I also removed File.mkdirs() from the sequence. (Yes, it was always returning false and I thought it was there to prime for .listFiles()).

Comment: Then also removed the requestLegacyExternalStorage from Manifest, and the app opened the file . I guess Android 10 now knows that the permission is allowed from the time the Legacy request was executed. Before, premissionManager had no effect ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems it relates to Android 10 permissions handling of **new apps**. During the problem no number of manual Android Settings Permission Manager Allow attempts would let the new app get listed under its '14 of 26' Storage permissions allowed, and now, since after the run with requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", Android 10 now shows '15 of 26' allowed and the app is now listed, whereas before I would have to search for it by name to do the manual setting of its permissions.